# Adding game center achievements to my game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center, achievements

I was trying to add achievements to one of my games, I made a list and started adding them with image and description in itunes connect, but I can't find a tutorial written in swift, and with a simple function like unlockachievement and the achievement id passed inside that

In my game, inside the viewdidload of the game over screen i made this

```
if (achievement condition){
//unlock achievement ("achievementID")
}
```

Is this a correct way to add achievements?In this view i have many stats passed from previous view so if I put the unlockachievement function here the popup should appear at the end of the game without distracting the player

For the leaderboards I made a func that gets score and leaderboard, I want to do the same for achievements, how do I do it?Is it possible?

I also read about achievement progress in the game center view,is it possible to avoid it?Especially with hidden achievements that should show up only when conditions are met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I solved

```
func loadAchievementPercentages() {
    print("get % ach")
    GKAchievement.loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler { (allAchievements, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("GC could not load ach, error:\(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            //nil if no progress on any achiement
            if(allAchievements != nil) {
                for theAchiement in allAchievements! {

                    if let singleAchievement:GKAchievement = theAchiement {

                        self.gameCenterAchievements[singleAchievement.identifier!] = singleAchievement
                    }
                }
            }

            for(id,achievement) in self.gameCenterAchievements {
                print("\(id) - \(achievement.percentComplete)")
            }

        }
    }
}
func incrementCurrentPercentageOfAchievement (identifier:String, amount:Double) {

    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        var currentPercentFound:Bool = false

        if ( gameCenterAchievements.count != 0) {

            for (id,achievement) in gameCenterAchievements {

                if (id == identifier) {
                    //progress on the achievement found
                    currentPercentFound = true

                    var currentPercent:Double = achievement.percentComplete

                    currentPercent = currentPercent + amount

                    reportAchievement(identifier,percentComplete:currentPercent)

                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentPercentFound == false) {
            //no progress on the achievement

            reportAchievement(identifier,percentComplete:amount)

        }
    }
}

func reportAchievement (identifier:String, percentComplete:Double) {

    let achievement = GKAchievement(identifier: identifier)

    achievement.percentComplete = percentComplete

    let achievementArray: [GKAchievement] = [achievement]

    GKAchievement.reportAchievements(achievementArray, withCompletionHandler: {

        error -> Void in

        if ( error != nil) {
            print(error)
        }

        else {

            print ("reported achievement with % complete of \(percentComplete)")

            self.gameCenterAchievements.removeAll()
            self.loadAchievementPercentages()
        }

    })
}
```

in the view did load I have this

```
if (conditions for the achievement)                           
    {

        incrementCurrentPercentageOfAchievement("achievementID", amount: 100)
    }
```

Tested now and it worked,now i want to do something different,I don't want to increment an achievement percentage but to set the percentage, for example:

Achievement - combo of 10 
 - Play a game
 - Combo of 8 and shows 80% progress on the achievement
 - Another game
 - Combo of 2

With the code I have now it should unlock the achievement because the percentage is cumulative, so I have to write another function to change the achievement progress percentage and to set it to 20
Now if in a game I met the requirements and unlock the achievement,and in the next game I don't get this condition again, the achievement is still unlocked, right?